# librería owldatetime cambiar formato de hora a 12 horas

Tags: javascript

estoy usando la librería owldatetime en un proyecto JS y Angular, pero al abrir el calendario me muestra la hora en formato de 24 hrs y lo necesito en formato de 12 hrs.

¿Alguien sabe cómo puedo lograrlo?

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.